# Install Windows 7 Professional to ASUS A43S

Tags: windows-7, formatting, partition-recovery, asus-laptop

Currently the operating system on my ASUS is Windows 7 Home Premium. I want to change it to Windows 7 Professional and also I want to format my ASUS.

I have read through this [article](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/restore-asus-laptop-factory-settings-53444.html) but unfortunately my laptop **doesn't have a recovery partition**.

I have bought a Windows 7 Professional CD but have no idea how to install it. **Which key should I press when ASUS logo displayed?**

This is what I get when <kbd>F2</kbd> key pressed.

[image: F2 Key Screen]

Comment: Press and hold the F2 button, then click the power button. DO NOT RELEASE the F2 button  until the BIOS screen display. Then set the BIOS to boot from your CD drive.

Comment: You need to swap #1 and #2 so the DVD is first. I don't know how to do that, you need to play with the settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### I have bought a Window 7 Professional CD but have no idea how to install it.

1. Insert the CD into your DVD/CD drive.
2. Press and hold <kbd>F2</kbd>, then press the <kbd>power</kbd> button.

   DO NOT RELEASE <kbd>F2</kbd> until the BIOS screen displays.
3. Set the BIOS to boot from your DVD/CD drive.

   Reorder the boot devices so the the DVD/CD drive is #1.
4. Press <kbd>F10</kbd> to save your changes and exit the BIOS.
5. The PC will restart and boot to the installation disk.
6. Follow the install instructions.

Answer (score 2):

Asus computers use the F8 key to choose boot up devices

Comment: Is F2 key for my laptop

Comment: Boot menu is not the same as the bios setup menu

Answer (score 1):

From the screen you are displaying, navigate down to Boot Option #2 and press enter.  You should be able to swap the position of the WDC (hard disk) with the Slimtype DVD (optical drive)  You need the optical drive to boot first (option #1) in order to run the installation DVD before Windows loads.  If enter doesn't allow you to select the alternative boot order, the numeric pads "+" and "-" or the Function Keys F5 and F6 should move them.

Press F10 to save and quit (restart) then press any key when prompted to load the Windows installation disk.

After the Windows installation has restarted, revert the boot order back to original.